# How do I replace nulls with 0 for multiple columns together in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigdata

I have multiple columns that include null values. I need to replace them all with 0 in one go without individually replacing for each column. How can I do that in big query?

Comment: you can't . it's not possible

Comment: I think - it IS possible! but looks like user is not even interested in answer since posted the question - so I am skipping this post! at least for now

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try below query:

```
#standardSQL
UPDATE <tablename>
SET 
    column1 = 0,
    column2 = 0,
    column3 = 0,
    .
    .
    .
    columnN = 0
where <condition>
```

Hope it will work.